# Strange visual artifact

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

During the course of fixing a bug where it looks like xamarin.forms was improperly letting go of a list view's ViewCell when controlled by a DataTemplateSelector I've come across a strange visual artifact that occurs on both iOS and Android. Interestingly, this issue goes away when the user scrolls sufficiently up and then back to the problematic area.

iOS:
[image]

Android:
[image]

One of the interesting things, and not shown in the pictures, is that on iOS it looks like two other templates that need to follow after are hidden behind the control. In the image we have 3 colors: Aquamarine for the outer stacklayout. Azure for the stacklayout on which we apply a BindableLayout, and then Beige for the inner stacklayout inside of the DataTemplate.

Code for the viewbehind:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
          xmlns:customcontrols="clr-namespace:DataFinch.Catalyst.CustomControls"
          mc:Ignorable="d"
          x:Name="root"
             x:Class="DataFinch.Catalyst.DataTemplates.SoapNoteDataTemplates.SelectListTemplate">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" 
                Padding="0, 20, 0, 0"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 MinimumHeightRequest="60"
                 BackgroundColor="Aquamarine">

        <Label 
            x:Name="LabelName"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="Black"
            FontSize="14"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

        <StackLayout x:Name="MultiselectList"
               Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                     BackgroundColor="Azure">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Beige">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                         VerticalOptions="Start">

                            <Image 
                                x:Name="image"
                                Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"  
                                VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                Margin="0, 2, 0, 0"
                                WidthRequest="15" 
                                HeightRequest="15">
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.SelectedItemCommand, Source={x:Reference root}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>

                            <Label        
                                x:Name="name"
                                Text="{Binding Name}"  
                                TextColor="Black"
                                VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                FontSize="14"
                                HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>


        <Label Text="Selection required"
                   TextColor="Red"
                   Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"
                   IsVisible="{Binding ValidationRequired}"
                   VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   FontSize="14"/>

    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

xaml.cs:

```
using System;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SelectListTemplate : ViewCell
    {
        private SoapNoteControlsViewModel viewModel;

        public SelectListTemplate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            LabelName.Text = viewModel.Label;
            MultiselectList.HeightRequest = (30 * viewModel.CheckboxItems.Count) + 10;
            
            MultiselectList.SetBinding(BindableLayout.ItemsSourceProperty, nameof(viewModel.CheckboxItems), BindingMode.TwoWay);

        }

        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnBindingContextChanged();

                if(BindingContext == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                viewModel = BindingContext as SoapNoteControlsViewModel;

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the overall parent listview which references the template selector:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv" ItemsSource="{Binding SoapNoteObjects}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SoapNoteDataTemplateSelector}"                      
                                  WidthRequest="500"
                                  SeparatorVisibility="None"
                                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <ListView.Margin>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="30, 0, 0, 0" />
                            <On Platform="Android" Value="30, 0, 0, 0"/>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </ListView.Margin>
                </ListView>
```

If I were to replace the Stacklayout with a Listview inside of the viewcell then the visual bug goes away, however, it introduces an issue whereby it looks like Xamarin holds onto an incorrect cell and well then throw an exception (only on iOS) like so: `NSRangeException Reason: Attempted to scroll the table view to an out-of-bounds row (8) when there are only 2 rows in section 0`

What exactly am I doing wrong in my viewcell that is creating this odd behavior whereby the element has a messed up visual state that is easily fixed only by scrolling up and down?

Comment: Did you try to set `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"` to the Listview and see if it works ?

Comment: I did, interestingly, using a FlexLayout solved the issue